# how to connect to database using java

Tags: java, mysql

How can I connect with java that interacts with my database? I am using the XAMPP for mysql
And I am having a problem knowing what port I am using.. I just copied the port which other are using from the internet But I dont really know what is my port number for the database
Also how do I check for the port going to data base?? `//localhost:3306`

HERE is my code:

```
    try{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    System.out.print("COnnection succesfull");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.print("Unable to connect     ");
    }


    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.print("Connection Stablished");

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.print("Connect cannot stablished");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check which port MySQL is running on, you can check a file 'my.ini' located in
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1 (Windows 8, might vary, but its the install directory).

The default is 3306 to my knowledge.

The code looks right, though I usually pass the username and password with

```
DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to specify port if you want to connect to XAMPP's MySQL. Try this, this works for me:

```
    String dbn = "yourdatabasename";
       String usr = "root";
       String pwd = "";

       String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+dbn;


       try {

                // Load the Driver class.
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                // If you are using any other database then load the right driver here.


                con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection (connectionURL, usr, pwd);


        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what did the exception said?

Comment: stablishedjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: well then, you have to download and install Connector/J first: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and then setting its path, this is how to set up path with Connector/J http://zobayer.blogspot.com/2010/12/setting-up-connectorj-for-jdbc.html